# Rails / Capistrano - How to set a staging server to show development logs in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, logging, staging

In my development logs, i get information like SQL statements made, etc.

However, when i deploy to a staging server, i do not get that in my development logs

How do i configure capistrano/rails to get that?

NOTE: I need it to be running in production env (database access, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly set the logging level in you config:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG
```

I would actually setup an environment specifically for staging. Create a staging.rb file in environment (using the above logger setting and a copy of the rest of production config), create an entry in database.yml and then start the server with a RAILS_ENV=staging flag.

Comment: hmmm, where do i set this if i only want it to happen for the staging server? There are several configuration files i see

Comment: added some more detail to my response :p

Comment: thanks a lot for the great answer! "RAILS_ENV=staging flag" -> i guess i can set this in staging.rb as well. thanks and accepted! =)